# How do I use the nth-child selector with jquery's child selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

This works fine:

> $("#element").find("> tr > td > i > a")

But I'm trying to use the nth-child selector to say that I want a specific numbered child. For example, I want:

> $("#element").find("> tr > td > i > a:nth-child(3)")

I'm not getting any results. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could select all the nth numbered children? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the markup

Comment: I'm making a Chrome extension, so it depends on the page that I'm on. The path that I specified above comes from this table here: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_least_expensive_films)

Comment: So you want to target every third anchor element that is children of i??

Comment: What you're trying is with your example finding `a` with 3 index number inside `i`. Are you sure this is what you want? Are you sure there's at least 4 `a`s in your `i`?

Comment: In that table there is only one a per i, each i does not have multiple children. What, exactly, are you looking to do?

Comment: I actually mean nth-child(0) for the table. I was using 3 just as an example. But yes, the number doesn't matter, I just want all the nth children of something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, this unless there's a great need to do direct descendant (the `>`) selectors, I don't see the need of including them, you can appropriately shorten your CSS selector too:

```
//Select 3rd <a> tag, within the context of #element td
$('a:nth-child(3)', '#element td');
   //or
$('#element td a:nth-child(3)')
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KGWuK/

Although, currently your selector provided with the question will only work if your [**HTML structure**](http://jsfiddle.net/xeJhL/) is:

```
 <td>
     <i>
         <a>One</a>
         <a>Two</a>
         <a>Three</a>
     </i>
 </td>
```

Which isn't a very *advisable* style of markup. That's because the original selector is selecting `<a>` tags of those that a *direct* child of the `<i>`

Comment: So just to clarify, you're saying that I can keep going down the chain, like $('#element tr td i a:nth-child(3)')?

Comment: @Jay [**Yes**](http://jsfiddle.net/KGWuK/4/), *if* your HTML structure is like the one in the answer. Otherwise no, because of the `i` selector.

Comment: The difference between using `ul > li` and `ul li` for example, is that the latter will select any descendants at a lower level; unless you have nested tables, this won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not using find as its not needed:

```
$("#element > tr > td > i > a:nth-child(3)")
```

This will find the  tag located within the  tag located within the table cell within a table row located within the element.

JSFiddle

Comment: `find()` is pretty significantly faster than large selectors like this . . . why wouldn't you recommend using it?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you have only 1 `a` with no sibling, i guess you are for the fourth element of your stack.

There is a jQuery method for that : `.eq()` :

```
$("#element").find("> tr > td > i > a:eq(3)");
```

or faster :

```
$("#element").find("> tr > td > i > a").eq(3);
```